# Proper steps to migrate PHP 5.6 code into PHP 7.3

Tags: php, mysql, php-7, php-5.3, migrate

we have developed previously in house system based on PHP 5.6 now we want to upgrade same code into PHP 7.3, we have not used any PHP framework we are using core way to write code means we are not using ANY PHP framework. what are the proper steps to migrate PHP 5.6 code into PHP 7.3

Comment: Check the official migration guides at https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.php

Comment: i have checked the doc, but in current system we have lot of functions and lot of pages, as shown in link we have check deprecated functions and whenever code is giving error we have fix that i understood but it will take to much time is there any simple and any another way to migrate

Comment: Did you try running the code as-is?

Comment: Can you give examples of what you had to adjust already? Why is it taking so long? Could you not just grep for the deprecated functions?

Comment: @Dharman for example the code written in PHP 5.6 page running properly but when i am running same code in PHP 7 some of the variables giving error like undefined index when i check code that variables is not defined but in case of PHP 5.6 its working

Comment: @SalmanA yes i have tried running code as-is

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? If you don't have any specific problem with migrating, there is no way to answer this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look through the migration guides at [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.php)

Have a look particularly at:

- Backward incompatible changes
- Deprecated features
- Changed functions

Go through each of the migration guides and check to make sure that any of the function and extensions that are changed/removed and make sure they are not used in your program.

I would then also test in a testing environment to ensure that all is working correctly still (would turn debugging on for this).

Answer (score 1):

I work on a PHP tool that handles PHP upgrades instantly and automatically from CLI. It's fully open source and available on Github:

- https://github.com/rectorphp/rector
- https://www.bram.us/2019/12/02/automatically-upgrade-your-php-code-from-5-3-to-php-7-4-with-rector/

So far it handles upgrades from PHP 5.3 to 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Apart from reading all the documentation guides at php.net

1. Set up a development/testing server using the PHP version you want
   to migrate to (7.3)
2. copy your app/code to the testing server
3. fix all the issues and bugs that spring up using php 7.3
4. upgrade production to 7.3
5. copy fixed code to production